# Именование взаимосвязанных таблиц и моделей (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, модель-данных, таблицы, именование

Допустим, есть таблицы две пары связанных таблиц:

- **posts** - посты
- **statuses** - статусы публикаций (черновик, опубликовано и т.д.)
- **users** - пользователи системы (ФИО)
- **statuses** - статусы пользователей (админ, редактор, модератор)

Возникает несколько вопросов:

1. Как правильно именовать таблицы и модели? Верен ли такой вариант:
   posts | post_statuses | users | user_statuses + модели: Post | PostStatus | User | UserStatus
2. В случае, когда есть связующая таблица между **users** и **user_statuses** (многие-ко-многим), то как будет называться таблица и её модель? user_status и UserStatus или же user_user_status и UserUserStatus ?

Comment: А разве `админ, редактор, модератор` это не роли?

Comment: Вы правы, но рассмотрим подобный пример. так то можно и посты назвать статьями или публикациями,а статусы привилегиями и т.д =)

Answer (score 1):

Уже придумали [Лучшие практики](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) для Laravel.

Немного примеров:

```
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+  
|  Что            | Правило     | Принято             | Не принято         |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+  
| Контроллер      | ед. ч.      | ArticleController   | ArticlesController |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+  
| Маршруты        | мн. ч.      | articles/1          | article/1          |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| Модель          | ед. ч.      | User                | Users              |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| Отношения hasOne| ед. ч.      | articleComment      | articleComments,   |
| и belongsTo     |             |                     | article_comment    | 
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
| Таблица         | мн. ч.      | article_comments    | article_comment    |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите в Ваш ответ ту основную информацию из содержимого по ссылке, которая непосредственно связана с вопросом MixJay. Иначе Ваш ответ, скорее всего, удалят. Спасибо.

Comment: Благодарю! С практикой ознакомлюсь в свободное время! )